# A tool to separate a wardrobe to a wall

Tags: walls, furniture

I have a 2.3 meters wall with a 2.0 meters IKEA PAX wardrobe against it. The wardrobe lean on the wall from its left side and from its "behind" side, and thus there is a 30cm (11.8" I think) gap on the right side.

The point is the wardrobe is kind of skewing to the right, because I didn't fix it to the wall. This was a big mistake but it's too late now and the wardrobe is unmovable.

I thought about puting some kind of traction bar between the wall and the right side of the wardrobe. (not sure about this translation, this is a bar that sportsmen put on doorframe and use to lift up). By screwing, I could push the wall and the wardrobe apart.

But of course there is no way I can find a 30cm traction bar.

What else could I use to prevent my wardrobe to fall appart ?

Comment: I'd be looking to repair and bolster the wardrobe, not install crutches against my walls. Please post clear, well-lit photos for help.

Comment: The structural strength of that furniture relies on things being square, and weight being supported directly through the sides, perpendicular to the floor.  If it starts to lean, you risk it self-destructing.  You would be smart to empty it out, then get everything properly aligned and tightened.  Then put it in place and fasten it to the wall.

Comment: @fixer1234 if I put a 30cm piece of wood between the wall and the wardrobe, it would force angles to be square again and avoid selfdestruct. I know I should fix it but now it cannot be done.

Comment: Post a photo of the situation and the wardrobe structure. We can't really offer advice with the somewhat vague word picture we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wardrobe it tall enough and the top is accessible, add a piece on [steel angle](https://www.lowes.com/pd/The-Hillman-Group-2-ft-x-1-1-2-in-Plated-Steel-Slotted-Angle/3053677) to the top at the corner where the top and the wall meet. Find the studs, screw it to that and screw it to the top with the proper length screws to keep them from going through.

Or you could get a piece that is not pre-drilled and drill your own at the stud locations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is best (steel angle bracket hidden on top) is the best idea but here is an alternative if that isn't possible.

It might not be the prettiest, but wouldn't a simple 2x4 (or even 2x2 or large wooden dowel) cut to size work here?

You can mount it to the wall to hold it in place and paint it the wall color so it isn't quite as noticeable if necessary as well.